# problem in .java

Tags: android

this is my java code and i really can not find where is my wrong

```
  package com.example.RateMates;



      import  android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.RadioButton;
      import android.widget.Toast;


  public class RateMates extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final RadioButton radio_red = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_red);
    final RadioButton radio_blue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_blue);
    radio_red.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
    radio_blue.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
} 
private OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
        Toast.makeText(RateMates.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

};

Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RateMates2.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

});
```

}}

Comment: }(red) 
    private OnClickListener radio_listener(red)= new OnClickListener()

Comment: @kostas_menu: What's the error message?

Comment: Illegal modifier for parameter radio_listener; only final is permitted

Comment: I have a *vast* dislike for *"Here's a pile of code, what's wrong with it?"* questions. And failure to specify the failure mode makes it much worse. @kostas: You're asking people to invest time and effort in helping you, the least you can do is invest some of your time and effort in writing a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your statements

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
next.setOnClickListener....
```

are in the body of the class, and that's illegal, you need to move these lines into the onCreate function instead.

<strike>However if you would have given the error message, I'm sure someone would have found this quicker.</strike> I haven't read the comments properly.
Still, it's not clear why you get this error because your OnClickListeners don't need to be final here, and my answer is (I guess) still valid.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use "final OnClickListener radio_listener" instead of "private OnClickListener radio_listener"

Comment: no this is not working..:(.if i erase the button:

Comment: if i erase the button and the startactivity the app runs and there is no problem...i dont know..